# Yii: ClientSide Validation on FileField and TextField

Tags: yii, validation, filefield

I have a yii form with a file field and a normal text field for supplying an external image url. I managed to get a normal server validation working which checks that only one of the two form fields is filled out (because you can either provide a local file for uploading OR an external picture URL). Important to notice is, that the attribute value of the "file field" seems only to be available after the `$_POST` var is set, meaning that a normal custom validation rule in the Model Class won't work since the `$_POST` value of the file field is only available after submission (in the `$_FILES` var).

But if you look at my provided picture below, I want also a ClientSide Validaton, so that the user gets immediate feedback that it's not allowed to fill out both fields. But how do I accomplish that? I'm sitting on this problem for about 2 days, half of the time on searching for solutions...I am new to Yii.

http://www.prism-informatics.com/images/demo.png

Best wishes,
S

Comment: If you've created your field using fileField(), I believe you can check the hidden field that's created along with it?

Comment: I tested Yii's own FileField validator. It seems that even that validator cannot validate the file field on client side. Guess I have to write my own clientValidation rule and put in some jQuery or javascript validation for the image field. But at least, I feel certain now ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure what your problems is as you didnt provide any code but i assume you forgot :

```
public function rules()
{
    return array(
        array('image', 'file', 'types'=>'jpg, gif, png'),
    );
}
```